# Jenkins - Discard old builds according to success/failed status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins Freestyle.
Is it possible to set a different discard behavior according to the build status? Just like a TFS build has. For example:
Failed - keep 12 last builds
Success - keep 5 last builds

After exploring [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) plugin, its not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Upto now there is no direct plugin to do that. You can check this source code and write one for your own. [discard-old-build-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/discard-old-build-plugin). It's not that much hard to write on seeing its source code. If not you can write a program in `Jenkins Script Console` to do that. Here I am attaching a [sample script link](https://superuser.com/a/1275105/652923) to do that.